# knockout- get parent obj at subscribe

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a javascript module, which holds an array of object.
Each object has an observable field called "level".
At update click, I want to have a separated array which holds only updated items.

So I create subscriber for each level-field, and on fired- I want to push parent-obj into the updated-object-array.

But How can I get the parent?

Here is a sample:

```
 var updatedData = [];

 function myModule(data){
         $.each(data, function addSubscriber(indx, item){
            item.level = ko.observalbe(level);
            item.subsriber(function(newVal){
                  updatedData .push(/*how do I get parent???*/);
            });
         }

}
```

Comment: can you post a sample data for what you referring `hold array of object` . can you add more code i'm confused .

Comment: updatedData.push(item); is what you need i think. when the subscriber is registered in each-loop item is the parent.